# How to assert substring in karate framework

Tags: karate

I am getting an array of URLs as a response. I want to check that each URL from the array contains a specific word.
How can I check this in karate framework?
My response is :

```
response {
  "docs":[{
         "url":"http://url/1.com"
         "title": "some title"
         },{
         "url":"http://url/2.com"
         "title":"ABC"
        }]
  }
```

}

Now I want to check that each url field value contains word 'url'.How can I check this as `match each $.response.docs.url contains 'url'` does not work for me.

Comment: Please post some code that shows your attempt to solve the problem, with examples of input and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [`match each`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each) syntax. Here is an example:

```
* def response = [ 'http://url-one.com', 'http://url-two.com', ]
* match each response contains 'url'
```

EDIT - after question was edited. Here is your working example:

```
* def response =
"""
{
   "docs":[
      {
         "url":"http://url/1.com",
         "title":"some title"
      },
      {
         "url":"http://url/2.com",
         "title":"ABC"
      }
   ]
}
"""
* def urls = $response.docs[*].url
* match each urls contains '/url/'
```

Comment: I just updated my query as match each does not  work for me.But I must say,Karate is awesome framework for API testing.I would like to contribute for the same.Keep up the good work.

Comment: can use the below as well?
* def urls = $response.docs[*].url
* match any urls contains '/url/'

Comment: @NagaRaj you can try it and see. if you have a question, please ask it with a clear example